# Selenium OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Im currently working on a python project with selenium and Im getting the error: "The handle is invalid". It occurs when I locate an element two times in the program. So I first do this:

```py
msg = WebDriverWait(driver, 120, 1).until(
        expect.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//textarea[@class='m-0 w-full resize-none border-0 bg-transparent p-0 pr-7 focus:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-0 dark:bg-transparent pl-2 md:pl-0']")))
...
msg.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

and then:

```py
msg2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 120, 1).until(
        expect.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//textarea[@class='m-0 w-full resize-none border-0 bg-transparent p-0 pr-7 focus:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-0 dark:bg-transparent pl-2 md:pl-0']")))
...
msg2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The problem has something to do with locating the exact same XPATH several times, but I havnt found a fix for it. I already tried restarting the whole driver after the first locating and then locate the second one in a new driver, but nothing works.

The problem has something to do with locating the exact same XPATH several times, but I havnt found a fix for it. I already tried restarting the whole driver after the first locating and then locate the second one in a new driver, but nothing works. I just want to use the same textarea 2 times, but it seems that maybe sending the RETURN key does something with it...